# Which Control to use in an Invoice System

Tags: winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

I need help regarding my project:
I am trying to make a Billing system like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKDvSnL1nFE 
but a windows desktop application.

the idea is: when the user enters product code/Id it it retrieves the products and associated information (i.e product name and price) from the database  and adds in the list.

I have no idea which control to use for the list, List View or Grid View or something else.

Comment: Please share with us what you have done. I am also searching for the same solution.

Comment: I have created the Invoice System, for that I have used DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use GridView because you have more control of your data, 
then you will assign a event to cells for refresh all product information; 
the event to use will be CellValueChanged.